# Display months/days or timestamps in another language than English

Tags: time-date

### Setup:

GUI version GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2015-07-25 on KAEL [compiled from EmacsW64.](http://emacsbinw64.sourceforge.net/)

Windows 7 x64 Dutch version.

### Situation:

When I'm evaluating the following snippet:

```
(format-time-string "%B")
```

It gives me "August" as result. In the Dutch language, we have "augustus" (spelled in another way, and without any case).

And my operating system is also in Dutch language. When I tried `(setq system-time-locale "nl_NL")` to no avail.
When I check the value of `current-language-environment`, it gives me `UTF-8` as value.

Another suggestions to get the days/months displayed in Dutch?

#### Update:

things are getting weird. On the Windows with the Dutch language (my work pc), I get "August". 
On my home pc with Windows with the English language, I get "augustus". And it's with the same Emacs configuration. So I guess it's not related to the operating system.

Comment: "nl_NL" might not be a locale that MS Windows knows about. Windows uses some non-standard aliases for locale names. I found this page, but I don't use Windows and wouldn't be able to figure out what in that table is the actual locale name: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318693.aspx

Comment: It should use language according locale settings on Unix-like systems. Not sure about Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting environment variable `LANG` to your language? Similarly, variables `LC_TIME` etc. - see the Emacs manual, node [General Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/General-Variables.html). That node also mentions MS Windows in particular: `Control Panel` > `Regional Settings`.

See also node [Language Environments](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Language-Environments.html).

If this helps, it might help to know that I found these nodes (and more) by using `i` in the Emacs manual. I typed `locale` at the prompt. `TAB` then shows you index entries that start with `locale`.

(Since I use [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles), I use `S-TAB` to see index entries that match `locale` also as a substring, which picks up a couple more entries, such as `set-locale-environment`.)

Comment: That was the answer. I noticed that I have set the environment variable `LANG` to C in Windows. I deleted that variable. After restarting the computer, I get the Dutch spelling for months. Your tip solved my question enventually, so thanks for your answer. And 50 bonud added too. Your contributions to Emacs community are really appreciated.