# How can I localize the calculation of org-table dates?

Tags: org-table

I have an org table I use to plan some dates every weeks. So I fix the first tuesday date of the month  and add seven days the following rows. Unfortunately I want the dates to be in french (Mar.) and org-table print them in english (Tue).

```
  |-------------------+---+---|
  | Date              |   |   |
  |-------------------+---+---|
  | [2021-08-03 mar.] |   |   |
  | [2021-08-10 Tue]  |   |   |
  | [2021-08-17 Tue]  |   |   |
  | [2021-08-24 Tue]  |   |   |
  |-------------------+---+---|
  | Total             |   |   |
  |-------------------+---+---|
  #+TBLFM: @<<<$<..@>>$<=@-1 + 7
```

How can I fix that ?

Comment: You can cheat a bit and use `org-display-custom-format` and `org-timestamp-custom-formats`: this overlays your preferred style over every time stamp in the file (possibly slowing down things: overlays are fairly expensive). However, if you want a French setup, you should start your emacs in that locale, e,g. `LANG=fr_FR.utf8 emacs`. That will *NOT* change every message into French (far from it), but it *will* change day names as used by `format-time-string` appropriately.

Comment: [This](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/57560/org-and-org-capture-uses-english-for-calendar-dates-no-matter-what-i-do/57561#57561) might also help.

Comment: Il solved the issue, simply activing M-x org-toggle-time-stamp-overlays.

Comment: I think I misspoke earlier: the custom-format stuff seems to use text properties, not overlays.